# Migrating from jMock1 custom invocation matchers to jMock2

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmock

I am using JMock-2.6.0. I have a map containing the names of methods and their expected return values.
I want to invoke a method on a mock object created using JMock.

Earlier I was able to this using JMock 1 as it follows following syntax:

```
mockObj.stubs().method(mymap.getKey()).will(new ReturnStub(mymap.getValue()));
```

But I am not sure, if there is a way to achieve this using JMock-2.

JMock-2's documentation is insufficient.

Comment: After reading through your question, it looks more like you're asking how, in Jmock2, to iterate through all the fields or setters in the mock and assign them a value. Your title makes it sound as if you're trying to access the mock's methods as a static import so you wouldn't have to type mock.setData(), rather just setData() as matchers would typically be called.

Comment: I have a map containing some specific method names of a particular class. Now I want to create a mock object with a specified behavior for those methods. The problem is, In Jmock 2, the mocked object behaves as an Instance of that class, so we can specify like: 'allowing(mockObj).getXXX();will(returnValue("sayYYY"))' but here, I dont know how to specify this 'getXXX()' because I am getting this String method name from a map which I can't control.

Comment: I've retracted my answer. Other than using reflection which I can post, I don't see a way any longer. However, if this is a DTO or VO you're mocking, you should just populate the real object.

Comment: I looked at the answer you posted earlier. In place of `allowing (any(Object.class)).method("get.*").withNoArguments();`, All I wanna do is `allowing (any(myMockObject)).method("getterFromMyMap").withNoArguments();`. I think, specifying the class type of my mockObject inside any() like `any(myInterface.class)` would work, as I am checking this expectation on my mockObject's context. What's your view? or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: If you simply want to loop through and check whether the method(s) with particular arguments (or no arguments) have been invoked, then yes. However, you're asking how to populate the mock with particular values from a Map which this isn't going to do. For that, you'd have to set the `.will` statements for each. I'll reinstate the answer if it helps you along however.

Comment: But I can add .will expectation for each of them, right? I mean doing something like: 
`allowing (any(typeToMock.class)).method(myMap.getKey());`
`.will(returnValue(myMap.getValue());`
will work, I guess. I am gonna give this a try.

Comment: I just did the same, you've got it. Throw that in a loop and you're golden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [this](http://www.jmock.org/match-object-or-method.html) is the documentation you've been looking for:

> Match Objects or Methods
>
> Although matchers are normally used to specify acceptable parameter values, they can also be used to specify acceptable objects
>   or methods in an expectation, using an API syntax similar to that of
>   jMock 1. To do so, use a matcher where you would normally refer to a
>   mock object directly in the invocation count clause. Then chain
>   clauses together to define the expected invocation.

Their example includes:

To allow invocations of any bean property getter on any mock object:

```
allowing (any(Object.class)).method("get.*").withNoArguments();
```

For example you can use the following `allowing`... portion in a loop to achieve a similar result.

An sample test:

Interface:

```
public interface ThingOneI {

    public abstract String getData();

    public abstract void setData(String data);

    public abstract String getRequest();

    public abstract void setRequest(String request);

}
```

Impl:

```
public class ThingOne implements ThingOneI {

    private String data;
    private String request;

    public ThingOne() {

    }

 @Override
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }


 @Override
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

 @Override
    public String getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

 @Override
    public void setRequest(String request) {
        this.request = request;
    }



}
```

Junit test:

```
import org.jmock.Expectations;
import org.jmock.Mockery;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ThingOneTest {

    Mockery context = new Mockery();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ThingOneI thingOne = context.mock(ThingOneI.class);
        Map<String, String> methMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        methMap.put("getData", "5");

        context.checking(new Expectations() {{

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : methMap.entrySet())
                allowing(any(ThingOneI.class))
                    .method(entry.getKey())
                    .with(any(String.class));
                    will(returnValue(entry.getValue()));
            }

         }});

         System.out.println(thingOne.getData());

    }
}
```